# Populating a hash from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have this array:

```
params[:types] = [type1, type2, type3...]
```

I would like to populate my hash the following way using the above array:

```
params[:hash] = { 
               "type1" => {
                   something: something
               },
               "type2" => {
                    something: something
               },
           }
```

Using a `for` loop like `for index in i ...params[:types]` just populates the hash with the last value in the array.

Comment: You've not tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `each_with_object` method to do this:

```
params = {}
params[:types] = ["type1", "type2", "type3"]
params[:types].each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = { "something" => "something" } }
```

That last line will return:

```
=> {"type1"=>{"something"=>"something"}, "type2"=>{"something"=>"something"}, "type3"=>{"something"=>"something"}}
```

Comment: Instead of `inject`, use `each_with_object`. It results in cleaner code: `params[:types].each_with_object({}) {|k, h| h[k] = { "something" => "something" } }` because it's not necessary to return `hash` at the end of the block. `each_with_object` knows to reuse that value.

Comment: Ah, cool! Thanks for the tip, just learned something! I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's not necessary to add "Edit:..." comments. Between my comment to your answer, and our ability to see the edit history of changes to your answer, we can figure out what was said. (All questions and answers on Stack Overflow have a revision history that users above a certain reputation can see. It comes in quite handy at times.)

Comment: Edited again, in that case :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet example that does what you need.

```
hash = {}
array.each do |a|                                                
  hash[a.to_s] = { "something" => "something" }                  
end
```

output:

```
hash                                                             
=> {
  "type1" => {
    "something" => "something"
  },
  "type2" => {
    "something" => "something"
  },
  "type3" => {
    "something" => "something"
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `a.to_s` is meant to convert the value of (say) the variable `type1` to a string, there is no reason to conclude that would be `"type1"`.  Better, I think, to just assume the OP meant `params[:types] = ["type1", "type2", "type3"...]` and drop `.to_s`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
params = { types: ["type1", "type2", "type3"] }

Hash[params[:types].product([{"something" => "something"}])]
  #=> {"type1"=>{"something"=>"something"},
  #    "type2"=>{"something"=>"something"},
  #    "type3"=>{"something"=>"something"}}
```

or with Ruby 2.1,

```
params[:types].product([{"something" => "something"}]).to_h
```

If you want a different hash for each element of `params[:types]`:

```
hashes = [{ "something1"=>"something1" }, { "something2"=>"something2" },
          { "something3"=>"something3" }]
```

then

```
Hash[params[:types].zip(hashes)]
  #=> {"type1"=>{"something1"=>"something1"},
  #    "type2"=>{"something2"=>"something2"},
  #    "type3"=>{"something3"=>"something3"}}
```